# Concourse 3.3.0 spitting hard to debug error: "json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface {}"

Tags: concourse

We are using some community custom resource types (`https://github.com/ljfranklin/terraform-resource` and `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-deployment-resource`). After upgrading to concourse 3.3.0, we've begun consistently seeing the following error on a *few* of our jobs at the same step: `json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface {}`.

This is fairly hard to debug as there is no other log output other than that. We are unsure what is incompatible between those resources and Concourse.

---

Notes about our pipeline:

We originally had substituted all of our usages of `{{}}` to `(())`, but reverting that did not lead to the error going away.

We upgraded concourse from v3.0.1.

The failing step can be found here: `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-ci/blob/6a73764d09f544820ce39f16dca166d6d6861996/ci/pipeline.yml#L731-L739`

We are using a resource called `elsa-aws-storage-terraform`, found here: `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-ci/blob/6a73764d09f544820ce39f16dca166d6d6861996/ci/pipeline.yml#L731-L739`

That resource is of a custom resource-type `terraform` found here: `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-ci/blob/6a73764d09f544820ce39f16dca166d6d6861996/ci/pipeline.yml#L45-L48`

A similar failing step can be found here: `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-ci/blob/6a73764d09f544820ce39f16dca166d6d6861996/ci/pipeline.yml#L871-L886`

Comment: Also seeing this with the terraform resource.

Comment: Can we see the pipeline/task configuration that leads to this?

Comment: It looks similar to the stuff reported in https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1340

Comment: Hey @ChristopherHendrix, the step that is failing can be found right here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-ci/blob/6a73764d09f544820ce39f16dca166d6d6861996/ci/pipeline.yml#L731-L739

Comment: @ChristopherHendrix here for us https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcf-releng-ci/blob/master/pipelines/ert/1.12.yml#L157-L162

Answer (score 1):

This is related to issue of not being able to define nested maps in resource configuration https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1345